# System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Service not available, closing transmission channel. The server response was: 4.4.2

Tags: smtp, timeout, channel, transmission

I get this error when I'm frequently sending some e-mail to a list of users. Say it sends 10 mails and 1 gives an error, then sends a couple more mails and gives the same error.

The code looks like this:

```
public static bool SendEmail(string toMail, string fromname, string from, string subject, string body, string BCC)
    {

        MailMessage mailmessage = new MailMessage("frommail@mail.com", toMail, subject, body);
        mailmessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mailmessage.BodyEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1254);
        mailmessage.SubjectEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1254);

        SmtpClient objCompose = new SmtpClient("xxxx");

        try
        {
            objCompose.Send(mailmessage); 

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { 

        }

        return false;
    }
```

And the error I get is this:

> System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Service not available, closing transmission channel. The server response was: 4.4.2 mailer.mailer.com Error: timeout exceeded
>     at System.Net.Mail.MailCommand.CheckResponse(SmtpStatusCode statusCode, String response)
>     at System.Net.Mail.MailCommand.Send(SmtpConnection conn, Byte[] command, String from)
>     at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.SendMail(MailAddress sender, MailAddressCollection recipients, String deliveryNotify, SmtpFailedRecipientException& exception)
>     at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)

can anyone please help, this bug is killing me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Disposing the smtpclient (objCompose) did the trick.

```
    // Summary:
    //     Sends a QUIT message to the SMTP server, gracefully ends the TCP connection,
    //     and releases all resources used by the current instance of the System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient
    //     class.
    public void Dispose();
```

Comment: MailMessage.Dispose()  (.NET 3.5)

Comment: Didn't work for me. Well... it got rid of the exception but now it just hangs when one sends an email or two.

Answer (score 6):

I like wrapping it in a using block.  That'll force the dispose and it's very elegant.

```
using(SmtpClient objCompose = new SmtpClient("xxxx"))
{
    objCompose.Send(mailmessage); 
}
```

Comment: This code compiles just fine under VS 2013, .NET 4.5